# How do certain sites such as reddit bypass adblockers to show ads?

Tags: javascript, html

certain sites like reddit are able to show adds even when I am browsing with an ad blocker, and some of the ads that bypass this are google advertisements. How do they do this? thank you for taking the time to read this have a nie day :)

Comment: To an ad blocker, advertisements are only advertisements if they advertise themselves as ads!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be your ad blocker settings. For example, Adblock**Plus** comes with **Allow Acceptable Ads** option enabled by default.

> Acceptable Ads are nonintrusive ads. They are the middle ground between ad blocking and supporting online content because they generate revenue for website owners.

Ad blockers work by blocking requests to a known list of advertising servers. Websites can also get around ad blockers by embedding ads in their content instead of using external advertising solutions (although this probably isn't the case here as you mentioned they are Google ads).

Answer (score 1):

https://adblockplus.org/acceptable-ads

It depends on what you use and what settings you have. This link shows an example.

As this shows, some ad blockers focus on blocking annoying ads because websites cannot keep running without any ads. This is a nice way to both website owners and users.

If this does not apply to you, please tell us what ad blockers you use and what ads you see.